# Prove the convergence of a series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If $a_n >0$ for all $n\geq1$, show that the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)}$$

converges.

Can someone check if my solution is correct:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{M}\frac{a_n}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_n)} = 1-\frac{1}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)...(1+a_M)} < 1 $$

Since the partial sum of the series is bounded, the series is convergent.

Comment: "Since the partial sum of the series is bounded, the series is convergent." - This, in general, does not hold.

Comment: Isn't that a proven theorem? Do you have an example that shows otherwise?

Comment: @Belgi seems to have misread like me. The partial *sums* are bounded, not just the individual terms

Comment: Well, given that the partial sum is bounded above, if you additionally prove that it is a non-decreasing sequence, then it is convergent. Nevertheless, I haven't checked your equality yet. It doesn't look straightforward.

Comment: By the way, in this particular case the sequence is trivially non-decreasing, since it is a sum of positive values.

Comment: @user136266 Take $\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i$. The partial sums are all within $[0,1]$, yet the series is not convergent.

Comment: @fgp, isn't it true that a series of _non-negative terms_  is convergent iff its partial sums form a bounded sequence. But in your example, the terms can be negative.

Comment: @SabyasachiMukherjee Yes. But the OP's answer fails to state that explicitly. You can't just say "The partial sums form a bounded sequence, hence the sum converges". You *have* to say "The terms are all non-negative, hence the partial sums form a *monotone* sequence, and since the partial sums are also bounded, the series converges".

Comment: @fgp,ah yes. :)

Answer (score 5):

Hints.

Indeed, your formula is correct and it can be proved inductively.

The series converges, because its partial sums form an increasing sequence which is upper bounded by $1$. Hence it converges, and its limit (i.e., the sum of the series) is also less or equal to $1$.

Comment: It should be pointed out that in this case, the ratio test cannot be used, because the limit of the ratio between two consecutive terms of the sequence (i.e. two consecutive partial sums) is one.